# Date.parse not working to check if a string is a date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I ran into an interesting case with Date.parse is returning a valid date instead of NaN as I would think is expected.

So `Date.parse('test 123')` returns `-58285678164000` and `Date.parse('123 test')` returns `NaN` like I would think.

Can anybody explain to me why `'test 123'` returns a negative number and `'123 test'` returns `NaN`, trying to see how I can check if a string is a date using `!isNaN(Date.parse(string))` but this case if giving me an issue.. and I'm just curious on why.

Comment: What browser? First one returns NaN in Firefox

Comment: If the string doesn't conform to the standard date specification, the results are implementation-dependent. It's treating the first string as `123-01-01`.

Comment: @charlietfl nice, I didn't even try it in Firefox, apparently it returns NaN in Firefox and Edge, but the issue I am seeing is in Chrome